# Upgrading jfrog artifactory from 6.23.42 to artifactory 7.68.11 url changed

Tags: apache, https, devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli

Earlier till 6 artifactory version we had a option to configure https port on server.xml ,
now from version 7 it is changed , here around 10 application teams are using a format https//artifactory.com:8543/artifactory in there code and during deployment
In artifactory version 7 it is pointing to http//artifactory.com:8082/ui

Later after some research I used apache to route http to  https , reverse proxy to https//artifactory.com but here I am unable to change to run as old url

my system.yaml file

```
shared:
    extraJavaOpts: -Xmx4g -Xss256k
    database:
        type: derby
        driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
        url: jdbc:derby:/opt/app/artifactory-oss-7.68.11/var/data/artifactory/derby;create=true
artifactory:
    port: 8081
    tomcat:
        connector:
            maxThreads: 200
            sendReasonPhrase: true
            relaxedPathChars: '"[]"'
            relaxedQueryChars: '"[]"'
        httpsConnector:
            enabled: true
            port: 8543
            certificateFile: "/opt/app/artifactory-oss-7.68.11/var/etc/artifactory/security/ssl/server.crt"
            certificateKeyFile: "/opt/app/artifactory-oss-7.68.11/var/etc/artifactory/security/ssl/server.key"
            extraConfig: 'SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2"'
access:
    http:
        port: 8040
    tomcat:
        connector:
            maxThreads: 50
            sendReasonPhrase: true
```

apache configuration to run on https

```
Listen 443 https

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    
    # General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration
    #DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    #ServerName www.example.com:443
    ServerName artifactory
    # Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
    # is not inherited from httpd.conf.
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    
    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on
    
    #   SSL Protocol support:
    # List the enable protocol levels with which clients will be able to
    # connect.  Disable SSLv2 access by default:
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    
    #   Per-Server Logging:
    #   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
    #   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    ProxyRequests off
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLVerifyClient none
    ProxyPass /ui/ http://artifactory.com:8082/ui/
    ProxyPassReverse /ui/ http://artifactory.com/ui
    </VirtualHost>
```

I also configured server.xml like the old one (artifactory 6 in artifactory 7)

It works on https like https://artifactory.com/ui

I want to configure as old url https//artifactory.com:8543/artifactory were as the applications team, monitoring team will not have any issue

Answer (score 0):

To change the port that your reverse proxy is listening on, you just need to change the configuration there.

You currently have apache configuration to run on https

```
Listen 443 https
```

Switch this line to

```
Listen 8543 https
```

and you will have artifactory accessible on https://artifactory.com:8543

Regarding the /artifactory endpoint, as you have noted, this was switched between 6.x and 7.x due to the change to a micro service architecture.

Now, when reaching the UI you go to https://artifactory.com:8543/ui
When trying to download Artifacts you still go to https://artifactory.com:8543/artifactory

This is baked in and can not be changed.